# How to compare rows of your datatable?

Tags: sql-server, resultset

Asuming the table is ordered,
Im looking for a resultset
that gives me the difference of value in row x and value in row (x + 1)

I can make a condition for value_rowx and one for value_rowx+1 then self join those so I actually subtract columns not rows.

Comment: Look into window functions like LAG en LEAD

Comment: 'Asuming the table is ordered' - that's a poor start , tables aren't ordered...and what equates to row x in your table?

Comment: Think of a table as a drawer full of socks. In your table, "row x" has no meaning unless there is some data in the table that gives it meaning.

Comment: You could improve this question bye adding table definition, sample data and expected outcome as text.